# Оправдано ли использование goto?

Tags: c, goto

Увидел в си проекте примерно такой код:

```
#define chk(_f)        if ((status = _f) != 0) goto Error;

int init() {
    int status = 0;
    someStruct *s = NULL;
    chk(someFunc1());
    if (s = (someStruct)calloc(1, sizeof (*s)) == NULL) {
        chk(1);
    }
    chk(someFunc2());
    return 0;
Error :
    if (s)
        free(s);
    return status;
}
```

В целом такую конструкцию с `goto` на сегодняшний день желательно использовать?

Comment: Как он может ее сохранять, если после выхода из функции никакого `s` вообще нет? Конструкция с `goto` - а где тут у вас `goto`? Есть только метка `Error:`, помечающая недостижимый код... И вообще - у вас какое-то странное приведение указателя на структуру к самой структуре...`s = (someStruct)calloc`

Comment: Покажите, где используется `goto`

Comment: `goto` вызывался только внутри этой функции, поэтому на счет указателя вопрос отпал. А можно ли избавиться от `goto` без дублирования кода?

Comment: Эти `goto` - всего-лишь защита от исключений. Аналог `try()catch()`. Не пользоваться `goto` - это смешно.

Comment: @Harry goto спрятался в chk.

Comment: Если фанатизм требует отказа от goto, то можно переписать на while/break. Но будет ли это читабельней?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, простите, а вот это  chk(someFunc1()); очень читабельно? Просто глядя на функцию init() реально понять, с какой стати она порой вдруг улетает на метку Error??

Comment: @AlexeyTen Изначально - когда я писал - никакого `chk` и близко не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что бы не ввязываться в религиозные войны, просто приведу пример на псевдокоде, где использование *goto* (IMHO) вполне оправдано. Подобные конструкции очень часто используются разработчиками драйверов. Итак:

```
if (! Условие1) {rc = -1; goto err1};
Действие1

if (! Условие2) {rc = -2; goto err2};
Действие2

if (! Условие3) {rc = -3; goto err3};
Действие3

... Основная часть программы ...

Отменяем Действие3

rc = 0;
goto err1;

err3:
   Отменяем Действие2

err2:
   Отменяем действие1

err1:
  rerurn rc;
```

Где такое может встретится? Ну, что бы не влазить в драйверы, например:

После запуска программа должна сделать следующие проверки:

1. Если первый файл для обработки не существует - создать его. Если
   создать не удалось - завершить работу
2. Если второй файл не существует - переключиться на stdin
3. Установить соединение с SQL сервером
4. Если не удалось - писать времнно в txt файл
5. . . .

Мне кажется, достаточно очевидным, что с использованием показанной структуры программы, использование *goto* не только возможно, но и желательно.

Кто с этим **не** согласен - покажите, как эти вложенные условия изобразить по другому и в какой кошмар превращается программа.

Answer (score 2):

когда я задавался подобным вопросом , я прислушался к мнению Линуса [переписка по goto](https://koblents.com/Ches/Links/Month-Mar-2013/20-Using-Goto-in-Linux-Kernel-Code/)

Answer (score 1):

Использование `goto` может быть оправдано в некоторых случаях. Оборачивание `goto` в макрос с невнятным названием - нет (***расстрелять***).

1. `goto` достаточно редко используется в современном коде (если вы не пишете код, который нужно уместить в ограниченный объем памяти), поэтому каждый такой переход желательно делать явным.
2. Макрос должен называться как макрос - в верхнем регистре. Если внутри него еще и спрятан `goto` то это нужно прописать в названии, например так:

   ```
   #define IF_FAIL_GOTO(fun, label) if((status = (fun)) != 0) goto (label);
   ```

   Если макрос с `goto` по виду никак не отличается от обычной функции, и, например, еще и инклудится из другого файла, то это вносит лишнюю неразбериху.

   ***Макроc должен кричать, что он макрос, а не функция, и кричать, если внутри него есть что-то потенциально не безопасное - типа `goto`.***

Вот такие вещи вообще лучше не делать (напоминает "если у тебя в руках молоток, то все превращается в гвозди"):

```
if (s = (someStruct)calloc(1, sizeof (*s)) == NULL) {
    chk(1);
    // разворачивается в
    // if ((status = 1) != 0) goto Error;
}
```

Лучше явно прописать

```
if (s = (someStruct)calloc(1, sizeof (*s)) == NULL) {
    status = 1;
    goto Error;
}
```

Comment: Абсолюьно верно — макро с goto / return внутри  и за его пределы — это качественно расставленные грабли на будущее.

Answer (score 0):

В данном конкретном случае - нет. Здесь макрос `chk` является грязной реализацией макроса `assert` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h
Поищите способы проверки значений в мировых проектах, таких как Linux Kernel или Qt